# Ajax returning into error and not in success

Tags: php, ajax

I have a trouble in my ajax call. When I tried to make a request from my PHP, the ajax returns in the error function and I don't know why because everything is okay. All of my data in my PHP are inserted correctly and I returned something like this in my PHP : `echo json_encode($response);` and when I checked the browser network then navigate my ajax request, it gives me the success but in my ajax callback success function, it doesn't execute instead it goes to error.

Here is my ajax request:

```
let fileInput = $('#file_input')[0];
  let postData = new FormData();
      $.each(fileInput.files, function(k,file){ 
          postData.append('requirement_files[]', file);
      });
  let other_data = $('#new_foster_applicant_frm_id').serializeArray();
  $.each(other_data,function(key,input){
      postData.append(input.name,input.value);
  });  
  $.ajax({
  url : baseurl+'user/post/new_foster_applicant',
  type : 'POST',                              
          data :  postData,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success : function(response) {                                  
              if(response.success === 'true') {
                console.log('true');
                    // $('.returen_savs').html('Please copy the transaction code serve as your transaction receipt...');
                    // $('.error_hadble').html('<div class="alert alert-success fade in m-b-15">'+'Transaction Code:'+response.transaction_code+'</div>');                                          
              }else {
                console.log('false');
                    // $('.returen_savs').html('');
                    // $('.error_hadble').html('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in m-b-15">'+'Error in submitting. Please try again later'+'</div>');                                          
              }
          },
          error : function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: `FormData` is not JSON. Leave out the `contentType` option.

Comment: What does a sample response json data look like? Are you sure response.success is set and is 'true'? You're comparing string type vs boolean there

Comment: The arguments to the `error:` callback are `( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`. `e` is not the error.

Comment: Use the Network tab of DevTools to see the raw response.'

Comment: As I said above, `e` is not the error, there's no point logging that. Log `textStatus` and `errorThrown`. Or just use the Network tab to see what was actually returned.

Comment: @Barmar the response from my network devtools is success which is came from my php success "true"

Comment: If DevTools says it was successful, but jQuery says there's an error, it usually means that parsing the JSON failed. When you look at the response, make sure there's nothing before or after the JSON.

Comment: @Barmar i updated my question and posted a picture of my ajax devtools success but it doesn't execute my success : function(response) instead it goes to console.log(e) which is the error

Comment: @Barmar 
type : 'POST',                              
               data :  postData,                             
               contentType: false,
               processData: false,

i removed the content type and the others

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the data you returned is really JSON type.

Please

(1) remove contentType:false and processData:false statements

(2) use method instead of type for 'POST' (assuming you are using new version)

(3) add JSON.parse to parse the JSON data returned

Hence , change

```
$.ajax({
  url : baseurl+'user/post/new_foster_applicant',
  type : 'POST',                              
          data :  postData,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success : function(response) {                                  
              if(response.success === 'true') {
```

to

```
$.ajax({
  url : baseurl+'user/post/new_foster_applicant',
  method : 'POST',                              
          data :  postData,
//          contentType: false,
//          processData: false,
          success : function(response) {   
var obj = JSON.parse(response);                               
              if(obj.success === 'true') {
```

Please also make sure that postData is not null in your case.

Comment: I received an error 
ncaught TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: is it true that you have say a number of file upload input boxes , but you did not use all of them to upload ? (i.e. you have say 5 file upload boxes, but you only upload say 2 ?)

Comment: i've choose one file

Comment: then you need to change your codes not to process the other (non -upload boxes). just check whether a file has been chosen for all the input boxes before you do the append. You know handling multiple files require more effort. But if in your case only one file is needed then please change your codes to handle 1 single file, and everything should be fine.

Comment: I mean i would like to make it one or more upload file

Comment: may i know how ?

Comment: Yes I understand (according to your codes you use requirement_files[] . But I suggest first change to use ajax to upload 1 single file first so that you can make sure that the ajax works, then amend your codes to upload multiple files. (it is always good to use a step-by-step approach to debug). You can do it.

Comment: I managed to log the error from the above code. It says parsererror

Comment: I suggest you remove (or remark) all parts related to postData first and then see whether it works. If it works, then it will be obvious that the postData (inputs and file uploads) are causing the parse error. Then you can debug it using a step-by-step approach.